# How I can speed up my algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, radix

I'm solving some problems and I can't solve these one. I have to write a code where user enter a decimal number, and I need to count how many times that number starts with digit 1 in other numerous systems.
Here is algorithm:

```
for (int i = 3; i <= n; i++) {
    int z = n;
    while (z != 0) {
        x = z % i;
        z = z / i;
    }
    if (x == 1) {
        brOsnova++;
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by " other numerous systems"?

Comment: I mean that number base can be number from 3 to infinity, because every number that is equal or above 2 starts with 1, so brOsnova is always 1.

Comment: What is meant by starts? This end-> 1000 <- or this end?

Comment: @dostanic_ did you come up with the solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accelerate it already by not checking the i's that verify

`i <= n < 2*i` since all of them will satisfy.
Therefore, check only `for(int i = 3; i <= n/2; ++i)` and then add (n+1)/2  to the final `brOsnova`.

I am sure it can be further accelerated and there must be some O(log(n)) algorithm, but maybe it would be far fetched... or a good candidate question for the `algorithm` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the loop, use this:

```
x = x - ((x / i) * i);
if (x == 1)
{
    ...
}
```

This only works for integer maths.

Comment: I need one variable for integer and one for rest, so I can know 1 is first digit.